# Firebase Storage/gcloud storage does not work with Unity Asset Bundles

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, bundle, assets

I'm trying to load remote asset bundles in Unity with a .bundle hosted on google cloud storage. Unfortunately it just does not work. On the Unity side of things I do get an error "InvalidKey" but it's not related to the issue.

1) My bucket is set to public.
2) the bundle Content-Type is set correctly "application/octet-stream"
3) The bundle has been tested and is loading without issue on both **AWS S3** and **Microsoft Azure.**

This is one of those issues where the Unity team will say it's not their problem because the issue lies on the google storage side. And on the Firebase side, knowone or not enough people have tested the remote asset bundle/Addressables setup.

Here are threads with other people hitting the exact same issue with .bundles and google cloud :

[Thread where people are having the same issue](https://forum.unity.com/threads/help-me-understand-addressables-remote-hosting.715991/#post-5057144)

[Some else attempting asset bundles + google cloud storage](https://forum.unity.com/threads/assetbundle-not-loading-with-google-cloud-platform-doesnt-work.716753/)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post.  This makes it easier for each question to be answered individually, and easier for people to find a solution to each problem in the future.

Comment: Possible solution to the Firebase Storage/Addressable (Asset Bundle) issues I've been hitting:

https://gitlab.com/robinbird-studios/libraries/unity-plugins/firebase-tools/blob/master/Storage/Addressables/README.md